# VB.NET: Add Cancel Event Handler From Other Class

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, progress-bar

I am trying to figure out a way to use events, handlers - to cancel an operation (a progress bar) from an asynchronous operation.

I have a class, ProgressBar, that is displaying the progress of an operation. It has a Cancel button (which is Friend WithEvents, typically generated, and has a Private Sub ButtonCancel_click). Nothing special.

The Cancel sets a public CancelButtonHasBeenPressed.

I want to be able to react to pressing Cancel, in another class.

I read about adding a handler to react to an event, and removing the handler at the end of the operation, which is what I should be doing.

Something like:

```
Public Function Mine(ByRef myProgress As ThatProgressWindow)
  ' some setup  
  AddHandler CancelEvent, AddressOf myProgress.ButtonCancel_Click
  ' create and call workers
  RemoveHandler CancelEvent, AddressOf myProgress.ButtonCancel_Click
End Function
Public Event CancelEvent()
Private Function worker(ByVal state As Object) As Object
  ' do work
  If ' how do I check for the event ? Then drop everything and run
End Function
```

The problems with the code/pseudocode above:

1) in the AddHandler, I should be adding an event that exists, something connected to the actual cancellation - but there is nothing in the ProgressBar, as is, to do that - how do I add a cancel ? I only have a Cancel button... So I had to make the button_click Public which is probably wrong...

Somehow, I was thinking that the user pressing Cancel would trigger that event... Is that not true ? I am truly new to this, and the web seems to assume, in all the examples, that the people looking at those examples are already experts.

2) How do I check that the event has been raised ?

As I tried to type "If" followed by an event name, in any form, Intellisense kept telling me that it was wrong.

Please, help me get started !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)?  It supports progress events and cancellation.

As an aside, don't use `ByRef` in your `Mine` function.  It is not required and could lead to subtle bugs down the road if someone maintaining your code doesn't realize the parameter is `ByRef`.

Comment: I am using a thread pool and I would like to cancel from inside the workers from the thread pool. I have considered BackgroundWorker for the call to the class that sets up the whole thing... but I don't have room on the real window for a progress bar, which is why I have a separate window. The Backgroundworker would not help for the multiple threads anyway...

Comment: The BackgroundWorker class uses the thread pool to run, and it isn't bound to any kind of window so it doesn't matter where you are showing a progress bar and/or option to cancel.  If you've got other requirements dealing with multiple threads, etc then you may want to update your question with those additional details...

Comment: You are right, it would be a cleaner approach than what I did. I will have to learn how to use it - have not found any practical examples, only very simplistic ones that I have not been able to implement with external classes and a separate progress bar. I have simplified my code to not use events - since I can't figure out how, I might later. I have been looking into using BackgroundWorker - not in this instance, but in general, for the past weeks, so I'll mark this as an answer for lack of an alternative.